# Responsive images in columns

Tags: responsive-design, grid-layout

I have a generally problem with responsive images: The websites I create often have two to four columns. When I have a three or four column grid with an image in every column, the images are very small. On mobile devices, the columns will be broken down to one column, so the images are displayed bigger.

But every responsive images solution only looks for the viewport, that means, on big screens the large images are requested (although the images are displayed very small because they are in columns) and for mobile devices the small images are requested.

Is there a responsive images solution which looks after the width of the image or the width of the surrounding element of the image?